# Why "mb_convert_encoding() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", if on php.net it accepts array?

Tags: php, mb-convert-encoding

```
$data = ['abcd', 'ddd'];
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'utf-8', 'windows-1251');
```

I get warning: mb_convert_encoding() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

But according to php.net mb_convert_encoding() accepts array.
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

`mb_convert_encoding ( mixed $val , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] ) : mixed`

Converts the character encoding of val to to_encoding from optionally from_encoding. If val is an array, all its string values will be converted recursively.

Is documentation incorrect or am I stupid?

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [changelog](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php#refsect1-function.mb-convert-encoding-changelog) from the documentation you mentioned describes:

> **7.2.0** - This function now also accepts an array as val. Formerly, only strings have been supported.

So it is going to work only for **PHP in version 7.2.0 and above**.